# CodeIgniter complains about undefined variable in view yet print_r displays results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am seeing some odd behavior in my basic PHP codeigniter app.

My output looks like this:

```
number of rows:  

    Warning notice  
    undefined variable: rows

number of rows: 10
```

What is most peculiar is that it looks like it is trying to double execute my PHP code, but I cannot figure out why.  Any insight is appreciated:

Code below:

model:

```
class foo extends CI_Controller  
{  
    public function index()  
    {  
           $this->go();
    }    

     public function go()  
     {  
        $this->load->model('model');
        $data = array('rows'=>  $this->model->count());  
        $this->load->view('view',$data);
     }  
}
```

model:

```
class model extends CI_Model  
{  
      public function count()  
      {  
          $query = "Select count(1) as count from table";
          $result = $this->db->query($query);    
          return $result->result_array();
      }   
}
```

view:

```
<html>  
<body> 
     Number of rows:  <?php print_r($rows[0]['COUNT']); ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Rooster I had to transcribe it across two distinct computers my code correctly reflects the `=>`

Comment: @Jessica it is defined in the `go` function of the `controller` inside of the `data` array.

Comment: `as count` followed by `$rows[0]['COUNT']` ? Also, it's `<?php print_r($rows[0]['count']); ?>` not what you wrote there. Also, CI has `row_array()` to get a single row. I am wondering how your code works.

Comment: @Twisted1919 again I transcribed this across multiple systems.  and updated the second function to be correct.  Yes it is ['COUNT'] don't know why, except I am using Oracle underneath.

Comment: @Woot4Moo what url are you accessing go from?

Comment: I tell you why, because you don't quote your alias, that's why :)

Comment: @Rooster `localhost/web/index.php/foo`

Comment: @Jessica What are you talking about?  Nowhere in my edit history did I ever not have "rows" within the data array.

Comment: try a redirect instead of a straight function call as your index function  redirect('index.php/foo/go');

Comment: @Rooster I was about to accept your answer but you deleted it.

Comment: @Woot4Moo sorry, I originally meant to type it as a comment because it was more of a guess,so I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like your index function is firing and calling go() before go is called.

I would guess your htaccess rules are written incorrectly.

try changing your index function to this

```
public function index()  
{  
    redirect('index.php/foo/go');
}
```

Comment: this did work for me, now it seems I need to fix my access rules.

Comment: well when you do, you can get rid of the index.php/ part of that redirect.